# Filter array attribute in jsonb column type using jsonb_array_elements_text

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

My Postgres version: 10.9

Using JsonB Column type which has a below structure:

```
columnName: favorites
{
"favouriteCity": "Boston",
"favoriteColors": ["Blue", "Red", "Green"],
}
```

Now, I want to filter all records which have favorite colors as Blue assigned.

I tried the below queries, but it didn't work.

```
select * 
from r_fav 
where favorites->>'favoriteColors' in ('Blue', 'Red')
```

or

```
jsonb_array_elements_text(favorites->>'favoriteColors' @>'Blue', 'Red')
```

Any idea how can I filter this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the contains all `?&` [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) with arrays:

```
select * 
from r_fav 
where favorites -> 'favoriteColors' ?| array['Blue', 'Red']
```

That will return rows at least one of the colors exist in the array. If want those where all colors are contained, use the operator `?&` instead

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you! Saved a lot of time.

Comment: @Sravan If that answer solved your question then please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, so that your question is marked as resolved.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reputation I guess. When I click upward arrow, I get this message: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"

Comment: You don't need to upvote, just click on the checkmark to accept the answer https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png

Answer (score 0):

Use an array of values, bear in mind both values must be included in `favoriteColors`

```
select
    favourites->'favouriteCity'
from
    t
where
    favourites->'favoriteColors' @> '["Blue","Red"]'::jsonb;
```

```
| ?column? |
| :------- |
| "Boston" |
```

Let me add this comment of [jjanes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/34857/jjanes):

> You could also put the key name on the other side of the @> operator. select favourites->'favouriteCity' from t where favourites @> '{"favoriteColors":["Blue","Red"]}'::jsonb; The two ways of formulating it will benefit from different indexes, so it may be worthwhile to try both

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=ab2cb4e9173c5cfb37bf0f6cc7268845)*

Comment: You could also put the key name on the other side of the @> operator.  `select favourites->'favouriteCity' from t where favourites @>  '{"favoriteColors":["Blue","Red"]}'::jsonb;`  The two ways of formulating it will benefit from different indexes, so it may be worthwhile to try both.